# Nested FlatList with both set for horizontal scroll causes the inner FlatList to always be vertial scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a FlatList with horizontal scrolling at the top of the page. When user taps an item, the rest of the page is rendered that includes another FlatList with horizontal scrolling.

What I am observing is that the second (inner) FlatList always switches to vertical scrolling regardless of the presence of horizontal value set to true.

Below is the code that demonstrates this.

```js
            <Layout style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                <FlatList data={["lahore", "lahore2", "lahore3", "lahore4"]} pagingEnabled
                    renderItem={(info) => (
                    <Layout style={{ width: 300, backgroundColor: "yellow", margin: 10 }}>
                        <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}>{info.item}</Text>
                        <FlatList data={["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]}
                            horizontal renderItem={(info) => (<Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}>{info.item}</Text>)} />
                    </Layout>)
                    } horizontal />
            </Layout>
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how best to achieve this visual experience even if it involves not using FlatList.

Answer (score 0):

You can not scroll nested both flatlist in same direction.